# How to apply "wherePivot" on collections data and not on relationship itself?

Tags: laravel, collections, pivot-table, relationship

Let's talk about an example. I have shops and products. Each product have its price according to the shop. The products have not the same price across shop.

I have returned for the view blade.php, the collections like this :

```
    $products = Shop::find($shop_id)->products; //list of products
```

Then in blade view, I want to find products with price greater than 50$. I use wherePivot on $product in blade, but I get "Method wherePivot does not exist".

And I think it is about "wherePivot" must be apply on relationship returned like:

```
    Shop::find($shop_id)->products(); // () at the end.this is relationship
```

This returns the relationship on which I could apply wherePivot. but I do not want the relationship, because I use foreach to display the products. So I want "products", the list , not relationship. And I need to filter on pivot column "price" too.

How can I make "wherePivot" work on list (of collection) in this case? not on relationship returned with parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

add `wherePivot()` method in relationship method in `Shop` model like below.

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')->wherePivot('price', '>', 50);
```

Comment: thanks but no. this is not I am looking for. Maybe it is because , I am not an laravel expert. I have : $products = Shop::find($shop_id)->products; and I return $products for the blade. and it is on this variable, I want to retrieve products with pivot column "price" more than 50. I cannot return relationship in blade (relationship : $products = Shop::find($shop_id)->products(); //check the parentheses). So I do not know how to do it.

Comment: so you have to add this line in relationship method in your model class.